# Get path to applescript stored on iCloud

Tags: macos, command-line, applescript, icloud

I wrote a shell script which calls an applescript to do some work. The applescript is in iCloud, so I'm manually writing the path to the document storage location...

```
 osascript ~/Library/Mobile\\ Documents/com~apple~ScriptEditor2/Documents/safari_get_tab_url.scpt
```

This is pretty ugly and looks fragile. I'm wonder if there is a cleaner way to get the path to this applescript file?

Comment: You can use quotes to cleanup the path for both bash and zsh shells. Depending on version, this will allow the ability to remove the \ before spaces in the path.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really that fragile, providing the following is true:

- The document will always be called the same and won't be renamed.
- The Bundle ID (`com~apple~ScriptEditor2`) will not change thus changing the path to the file.
- iCloud must remain enabled on the account.

Since it's only the first one you'd have to worry about, it seems perfectly fine to do just what you're saying, since a normal path would have the same problem anyway (normal = without any form of linking).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but how about this:

---

```
path to me                                                                      
return POSIX path of the result
```